# Thorax model validation error call back not working

Tags: javascript, validation, backbone.js

I have a thorax model which I want to validate before saving. I have written validate function in the model and return a error if my validation fails(like follows)

```
var myModel = Thorax.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: '...',
    validate: function(){
        ....
        return this.errors.length > 0 ? this.errors : false;
    })
});
```

I call save on the model and pass call backs as follows.

```
var options = {
    success: function () {
         alert(success);;
    },
    error: function (error) {
        alert(error);
    }

};
mymodel.save(null,options);
```

the success call back works but not error one. I'm using thorax 2.0.0. Any ideas ??

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
validate: function(){
    ....
    return this.errors.length == 0;
})
```